# ApexPages.message not showing in first VF when redirect to another

Tags: visualforce, controller, redirect

I have two VF with the same controller, the second one I used it as a CSV file, I need that in the First VF a Apex.Message shows and then downloads the CSV file.

Part of the Controller.

```
            if(eAs.size() == 0){
                System.debug('Success');
                ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.CONFIRM, 'Carga exitosa de - ' + ams.size() + ' registro(s) de '+ ams.size() +' Asiganicón de Módulo.'));                

            }
            else{
                System.debug('Error');
                ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.WARNING, 'Asigaciones de Módulo: ' + tF + ' de ' + ams.size() + '.'));
                PageReference retURLExcel = new PageReference('/apex/CsvErrors');
                retURLExcel.setRedirect(false); 
                return retURLExcel;                      

            }
```

**The problem is that the warning message is showing in the second VF(csv file) and not in the first one**

Comment: Hello there, glad you found your way to sfse. To help you properly, we need a little more code context. As we are also dealing with VF, we need also VF markup.

Comment: You need to return a null PageReference.